# Permissions on /var and /var/log

Tags: permissions

I set all the permissions and recommended by the documentation.

However, anyone can still see the log files from the browser since the var/log folder has read permission.

How is that handled ?  by .htaccess?
I have that file in place
Maybe is not being recognized by the server ?

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/var/.htaccess this file? you probably have something wrong in your config, what is your php handler? apache module or php-fpm?

Answer (score -2):

restrict just the log folder access to the group www-date

Comment: which user is writing your logs ?

Comment: this doesnt answer the question on "how is this handled?".  The solution you are offering is just a patch and its not documented anywhere.

Comment: this is very bad answer. if you mean `www-data` then its already has read access to that folder, and it will not block anything from opening it...